# Align form elements in jqgrid Add / Edit forms

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid were in the required columns field in the form have prefix "*". But this is causing the form element to not align. To solve this problem I added single prefix to all non required form elements. This work around does not work. The other workaround is to add suffix. Can the alignment issue be solved with prefix option? If yes, then how?

`UPDATE`

See below image. All the fields with leading "*" is not aligned with other elements in the form.

[image]

Comment: Please show one evidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue I added `"* "` to all required field prefix property and for other fields I added `"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"`. On doing this the elements are aligned properly.